# What is the difference between ('string') and ('string',)?

Tags: python

It's all in the question. I am having a hard time figuring what the difference is between `('string')` and `('string',)`

What does the ending comma adds ?

Comment: One is a grouping, the other a tuple. The **comma** makes it a tuple.

Comment: thank you, i will do more searches in that direction :)